# Escaping single quotes in C# powershell runspace

Tags: c#, powershell, escaping, exchange-server, powershell-cmdlet

I am trying to run Exchange cmdlets using System.Automation dll in C#.

In http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315325.aspx, they have said that for escaping single quotes, we basically need to append it with another single quote

For example,

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Write-Host 'Live and let le''arn'
Live and let le'arn
```

However, when I try to do the same thing with my cmdlet,

```
New-Mailbox -Name 'user1.''.cn'
```

The new mailbox is actually created with name as user.''.cn. We would like it to be user.'.cn
Code to execute this cmdlet is as follows:

```
AutomatedRunspace.Command command = new AutomatedRunspace.Command(cmdlet.Command);

foreach (CmdletParameter param in cmdlet.GetParameters())
{
    command.Parameters.Add(param.Name, param.Value);
}
pipeline.Commands.Add(command);
```

Is there anything we can do to correctly escape it?

Answer (score 0):

When you're invoking cmdlets in C#, you need to also worry about the C# string quoting behavior.  It's not clear in your question what exactly you're setting the Name parameter to in C# code.  I would try this:

```
string nameArg = "user1.'.cn";
```

That is, the PowerShell API should be bypassing the parameter parsing phase since you're supplying the argument directly via the API.